# Using `TCA_DESCR` for `tt_content` row in depend of its `CType`

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-6.2.x

The configuration in `TCA_DESCR` is used for CSH help text; something like `$GLOBALS['TCA_DESCR'][$table]['columns'][$field] = array('description' => ...)`. Does TYPO3 CMS provide anything to use this configuration for the subtypes (`CType`) of `tt_content`?

I ask because you can change a field label for a row in `tt_content` dependent on its subtype (`CType`). E.g. naming the field `header` of a content object with the type `Foo` as `Bar` instead of `Header`. But it seems you can't change the CSH help text because when I look into `FormEngine::getSingleField()` the helper function `BackendUtility::wrapInHelp()` is only used with three parameters and thus the default CSH help text is used. It doesn't make any sense IMO because when I define a custom subtype with a custom front-end template I know exactly what this field is used for in that case and it may differ a little bit from another subtype.

So the only possibility I see is to write an ugly handler for the hook `getSingleField_postProcess` of `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tceforms.php']` to get what I need. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The table description is bound to each table/field. Therefore you cannot make it change based on some condition, unless you hook into the core do this yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the Hook I mentioned above I'll get rendered markup, so I'll not follow this path. Instead I just introduce new fields when a custom content type this requires. But it's a little bit curious that you able to change a label based on some conditions but the help text stays constantly.

Comment: The reason why you can change the label is, that you can use a field for different data, depending on the chosen record (sub-)type. An example would be tt_content. I recommend to not to do this, but rather to use more fields and only display needed fields in your current sub-type or to use different tables altogether.

Comment: Exactly! And this possibility is half baked when you not able to do same for the label help. So IMO either you can 'misuse' an existing field for your own purpose completely or you don't but the current state is something between. Anyway I already wrote what you suggest, because of the lack of support by changing the label help of existing fields I have to write for every property of my custom type new fields (columns); which is in some cases a little bit stupid (e.g. something like a `title`).